# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException, android.view.InflateException with ImageButton

Tags: android

I receive the error below, mostly on Android 4.1 and 4.4:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service se.weblink.weblinkunified.services.FloatingWindowService: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2406)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #68: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at se.weblink.weblinkunified.services.FloatingWindowService.addViewToWindow(FloatingWindowService.java:122)
at se.weblink.weblinkunified.services.FloatingWindowService.onCreate(FloatingWindowService.java:92)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2396)
... 10 more
```

The addViewToWindow function:

```
    final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    popupWindow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.window_floating_call, null);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = setupLayoutParams();

    final View.OnClickListener clickListener = getViewClickListener();
    final View.OnTouchListener touchListener = getTouchListener(params);
    popupWindow.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    popupWindow.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

    final View overlayView = popupWindow.findViewById(R.id.overlay_view);
    overlayView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    overlayView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

    final View topContainer = popupWindow.findViewById(R.id.call_top_container);

    buttonContainer = (LinearLayout) popupWindow.findViewById(R.id.call_bottom_container);
    buttonContainer.addView(getActiveCallButtons());

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final Resources resources = getResources();

    topContainer.setBackgroundColor(sharedPreferences.getInt(Constants.THEME_COLOR_PRIMARY, resources.getColor(R.color.accent_color_default)));

    setupCloseButton();

    windowManager.addView(popupWindow, params);
    popupWindow.setTranslationY(Tools.getDensityIndependentSize(-120, resources));
    popupWindow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And the xml file "window_floating_call":

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/call_top_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/accent_color_default"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_image"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_initial_label"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/incoming_call_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_image"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_bright"
        android:text="@string/incoming_call"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_name_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/incoming_call_label"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_image"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_bright"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_number_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/contact_image"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_name_label"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_bright"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/overlay_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/call_bottom_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/call_top_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >



</LinearLayout>
```

I can't figure out what causes the error. The problem does not occur on Android 5.1. And I don't seem to get why this code wouldn't be able to run on Android 4.1, 4.2, 4.4.

I appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Forgot to include the android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException error. But the exception says that the resource file is not a drawable. I have the image ic_action_cancel in all other drawable folders (drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi etc.) except the main drawable folder(drawable). I tried adding the .png file to the main folder but it did not work.

Comment: maybe 4.4 doesn't support it.

Comment: problem is  with your style(Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton) that you are adding to ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem as yours.I firstly used my `inflateUtils` that write by myself.

The code is:

```
public static View inflate(int id) {
    return View.inflate(getContext(), id, null);
}
```

And the `getContext()` method return a `applicationContext`. And it occurred `InflateExcepition`.

And now I change to use `View.inflate(context, resId, null)`, and the context is my activity. And it worked fun now! hope that can help you.

sorry for my poor English!